# how to send a "break" when debuging embeded system?

Tags: linux, embedded

all,

when debugging embedded system, as you know, we usually communicate target device over an uart console. Now I want to test "Magic sysrq" function in linux kernel, which need to send a "break" to console driver. I've found what does the "break" mean, seems I need to keep TX-line  electrical low  level for a while.
My question is how to send this break "character", from APUE(Advanced program in unix), I have to call function "tcsendbreak", which mean i have to write a program. I wander if i can use some specical keys to send that, like ^C etc.
Don't methon "echo "x" > /proc/sysrq-trigger"", I know that, just have a discussion on other way :)

This is my terminal settings, I talk with target with ckermit.

```
stty -a < /dev/ttyUSB0 
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc 
-ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl  
echoke
```

Comment: What software are you using to talk to it?

Comment: I use ckermit, what i've noticed is the uart has set ignbrk, should i unset this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.math.utah.edu/lab/man/kermit.html), it looks like `Control-\ B` will send a break in C-Kermit.

Other ways...

> One way to send a break is to:
>
> 1. Switch to a lower speed
> 2. Send a Nul (0) or an @ (40<sub>16</sub>) -- a character with many contiguous 0 bits will produce the framing error called a BREAK.
> 3. Switch back to the original speed
>
> As you noted, the other way is to use the `<termios.h>` line control
>   functions.
>
> ```
> #include <termios.h>
>
> int tcsendbreak(int fildes, int duration); // "duration" is ignored
> ```

Comment: I've got your point, but I don't think this is convenient, i have to disconnect and reconnect and change uart settings.

Comment: What about the ^B suggestion then?  Or since C-kermit is open source, patching the tcsendbreak() into it as a response to some other user trigger mechanism.